# Identity auto jumping in SQL Server LocalDb

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a C# application and uses SQL Server LocalDb database as I know.

One time I attached my database to SQL Server 2012 and then detached it. Now one of my users informed me that the table id jumped from 36 to 1036. After that I changed user database to new again, it jumped from 2 to 1003.

I see many solutions for this problem, but I don't have like this problem to my old user that they have old version and database. My new users have this problem also they don't have SQL Server 2012 on system, just LocalDb.

Do you think if I remove whole database and create new one from C# it can help me or not?

Comment: This is a common issue when you attach a database with existing data and then perform insert to it. 1 way to fix this is to attach the schema only without the data in-case it's not that important for you. You can always script the local db and execute it on your new database.

Comment: If i create new database it help me or no

Comment: Better to design the database in a way that such a minor problem would not matter. If your IDs are not `smallint`, you have 2,147,483,647 IDs disponible.

Comment: Creating a new empty database on SQL Server will reseed IDs.

Comment: *LocalDB* ***IS*** SQL Server - and it's version 2012 or newer.....

Comment: @marc_s on my customer pc its local db 2012

Comment: Yeah. Happens if someone does not read the documentation. This is fully documented. It is done to have more performance. you can set that ti 1 - or you realize an ID should never be exposed to a user.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some other reasons for this id gaps, it may be due to automatic server restart after installing an update.

You can use below two choices

Use trace flag 272 o This will cause a log record to be generated for each generated identity value. The performance of identity generation may be impacted by turning on this trace flag.
Use a sequence generator with the NO CACHE setting

Setting Trace Flag 272 on SQL Server 2012 that you are expecting here

Open "SQL Server Configuration Manager"

1. Click "SQL Server Services" on the left pane
2. Right-click on your SQL Server instance name on the right pane
   ->Default: SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER)
3. Click "Properties"
4. Click "Startup Parameters"
5. On the "specify a startup parameter" textbox type "-T272"
6. Click "Add"
7. Confirm the changes

Comment: No problem is that my identity jumping from 3 to 1004

Comment: dear @Ryan Riel i have sql local db 2012 on my customer pc

Comment: i dont have sql server configuration manager in my client pc its just sql local db 2012

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 below scenario....

1. Are you getting everytime 1000 jump (I mean for every record you insert) then you go to design of table and check for "Identity Increment" and "Identity Seed" both should be 1.
2. If you get sometime this jump(some random number) then you are trying to insert  record in table but it is failing , so for each fail insert, identity value will increase by 1.

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: Dear Ravi i check this two option its correct some time its jump from 36 to 78 for some users its diffrent

Comment: so looks like you are trying to insert the record in the same table but it is failing before the actual insert

Comment: You can do one more thing, right click on table and check for "View Dependencies", you might get some idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way SQL Server works now. It reserves a pool of 1000 ids for each table on start. Any of the reserved identities not used on shutdown is discarded, and a new pool of ids reserved on start.

If you really need sequential identities, you can create an identity table where you control the generated ids. It is not the prettiest or preferable way but gives you more control over identities. One upside is that it gives you some interesting identity generation capabilities. For example, consider you need  to generate an incremental number, starting from 1 for each customer for every year, then you use identity tables.

PS: an identity table is a simple table with one row and one column per id.
for `Customer` table, there is a `CustomerIdentity` table where you store latest id. id generation is done manually by using update statement.

Comment: mean create    like this ' CREATE SEQUENCE Id_Sequence
    AS INT
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 0
    NO MAXVALUE
   NO CACHE'